# Huffman Encoding tree

Tags: c++, huffman-code

I am trying to build an Huffman encoding tree.

**main:**

```
int main()
{
    // Read frequency table and build Huffman tree.
    NodePtr huffman = build_tree();
    print_tree(huffman);

    // Free the allocated memory.
    free_memory(huffman);

    return 0;
}
```

The input should be on the form:

```
number of letters
"letter" number of occurrences
"letter2" number of occurrences
```

So far I have not got it to work. Any ideas what might be wrong?

**build_tree function:**

```
NodePtr build_tree()
{
    int characters;//number of characters
    cin >> characters;
    char letter;
    int freq;
    HuffmanPriorityQueue queue;
    NodePtr p;
    for (int i = 0 ; i < characters; i++)
    {
        cin >> letter;
        cin >> freq;
        NodePtr temp = new HuffmanNode(freq, letter);
        queue.push(temp);
    }
    for (int i = 0 ; i < characters - 1 ; i++)
    {
        NodePtr a = queue.top();
        queue.pop();
        NodePtr b = queue.top();
        NodePtr p = new HuffmanNode (a->frequency + b->frequency, NULL);
        queue.push(p);
    }
    return p;
}
```

**The print function:** Which was supplied so I assume it is correct.

```
void print_tree(NodePtr root, int indent = 0, string prefix = "")
{
    // External nodes are not printed.
    if (root == NULL) {
        return;
    }

    char letter = ' ';
    if (root->is_leaf()) {
        letter = root->letter;
    }

    cout << string(indent, ' ') << prefix << "(" << letter << " [" << root->frequency << "]";
    if (root->is_leaf()) {
        cout << ")" << endl;
    } else {
        cout << endl;
        // Print left and right subtrees with the appropriate prefix, and
        // increased indent (by INDENT_SIZE).
        print_tree(root->left, indent + INDENT_SIZE, "0");
        print_tree(root->right, indent + INDENT_SIZE, "1");
        cout << string(indent, ' ') << ")" << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like you're not too new to StackOverlflow, but "So far I have not got it to work" is not the best place to start a question. What does not work, did you spot any trouble in debugging, etc.

Comment: Yes, I am new to Stackoverflow and relatively new to C++ so excuse my ignorance :).
The error is in the build_tree function and I can't figure out where it's origin come from even though I've tried the debugger(Not an expert in debugging either unfortunately :( )

Comment: I think that `NodePtr p = new HuffmanNode (a->frequency + b->frequency, NULL);` should be something like `NodePtr p = new HuffmanNode (a, b);`.

Comment: There is no `pop` for `NodePtr b` ?

Comment: Yes the pop was missing for b :). 
I wan't p to be a new node that has the frequency of a+b and it does not hold any value for "letter"

It is defined
HuffmanNode(int frequency, char letter)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have several problems:

- The outer `NodePtr p` is never assigned.
- There is no `pop` for `NodePtr b`
- New node doesn't refer to its children `a` and `b`
- You don't return the root.

So following may help:

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < characters - 1 ; i++)
{
    NodePtr a = queue.top();
    queue.pop();
    NodePtr b = queue.top();
    queue.pop();
    NodePtr p = new HuffmanNode (a, b); // The new node has two children `a` and `b`.
    queue.push(p);
}
return queue.top(); // Return root.
```

Comment: Beautiful, it is working now. 
I had 
NodePtr p = new HuffmanNode (a->frequency + b->frequency,NULL);
        p->left = a;
        p->right = b;
Instead of NodePtr p = new HuffmanNode (a,b)